# copying a file from a USB storage if it exist with udev rules

Tags: 14.04, usb, bash, mount, udev

I have a simple udev rule to match USB storage devices which runs a simple script that looks for a file in the USB. I'm using the `usbmount` package in order to automatically mount the USB. As the documentation says, the USB devices will be mounted to `/media/usb{0..7}`.

When the USB storage device has been detected I run this script

```
#!/bin/bash

options=("usb0" "usb1" "usb2" "usb3" "usb4" "usb5" "usb6" "usb7")

for dir in "${options[@]}"
do
    lookup="/media/$dir/luah_v2_version.zip"

    if [ -e "$lookup" ]; then
        cp $lookup /home/luah
        exit 0
    else
        echo "could not find $lookup" >> /home/luah/log
    fi
done
```

The thing is that when the script is ran automatically after the USB was connected, it results in a log file where it says that the file could not be found in any of the directories above (while it does exist). When I then manually run the script it works and copies the zip file to where I wanted.

I've tried to set a wait time before the script executes of 10 seconds to see maybe the USB was not mounted by the time the script ran but I get the same end result.

Comment: Have you checked if `/media/usb[0-7]` is the actual path? The script works for me, and I can't see anything wrong with it (aside from the unquoted `$lookup` in `cp $lookup /home/luah`, but that is not the problem in this case)

Comment: @kos Yes I've ensured many times that these directories exist. Also, please note that I mentioned in my question that when I run this script `manually` then it works just as expected

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that. Then I have no clue, +1

Comment: @kos that's frustrating :/ Did you manage to reproduce that on your end?

Comment: I couldn't try with udev since I don't have an USB drive handy other then the one I'm booting from. However I'll try this later and let you know, since I want to start playing with udev as well, it might come handy

Comment: @kos thanks for that :) I will be waiting for your findings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably usb has not been mounted at the time your rule is processed. Try adding a hook to the usbmount i.e. create a file named */etc/usbmount/mount.d/10_autocopy.sh*

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -f $UM_MOUNTPOINT/luah_v2_version.zip ] &&  cp $UM_MOUNTPOINT/luah_v2_version.zip /home/luah
```

then make it executable:

```
chmod +x /etc/usbmount/mount.d/10_autocopy.sh
```

**variables set for mount scripts (/etc/usb/mount.d):**

- UM_DEVICE: mounted device
- UM_MOUNTPOINT: mount point of the device
- UM_FILESYSTEM: filesystem type
- UM_MOUNTOPTIONS: mount options
- UM_VENDOR: vendor string of the device
- UM_MODEL: model or product string

**variables set for unmount scripts (/etc/usb/umount.d):**

- UM_DEVICE: mounted device
- UM_MOUNTPOINT: mount point of the device
- UM_FILESYSTEM: filesystem type

**Note:**

- all scripts are by default executed as user root.
- usbmount uses the syslog facility if VERBOSE=yes - */etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf*

Comment: How does this script get's executed? where does the `$UM_MOUNTPOINT` is being created? I guess that what you are trying to do is to add a hook that whenever usbmount is mounting a USB it will look into it with the script you wrote above?

Comment: It doesn't seem to copy the file to the desired location. Any idea why?

Comment: I just changed the name of the file to be `10_autocopy` instead of `autocopy.sh` and it works. Thanks a lot! I was looking for any hooks that usbmount may trigger but there was no documentation so I didn't know about this. THANKS!

Comment: It would be great if you could list the variables that are available in those scripts for reference. Also, under what user does the script run and does it have the `PATH` variable set anywhere else in the system? Does it also have an error log?